# Show that for any event $A \in \mathcal{B}$, $P(A) = \alpha P_1(A) + (1-\alpha)P_2(A)$ yields a valid probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P).$

Tags: probability-theory

The problem is: Suppose that $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P_1)$ and $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P_2)$ are probability spaces. Further suppose $0\leq \alpha \leq 1$. Show that for any event $A \in \mathcal{B}$,

$P(A) = \alpha P_1(A) + (1-\alpha)P_2(A)$

yields a valid probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P).$

I know that if you plug in a number for $\alpha$ like $.5$ you're essentially cutting up the same probability space in half then adding the halves. How would one show this theoretically?

Answer (score 1):

For the new [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$, the sample space set $\Omega$:

- $\Omega \ \ \not \emptyset$,

and the $\sigma$-algebra, the set of possible elements:

- $\Omega \in \mathscr{F}$,
- $\mathscr{F} \text{close with }()^c$,
- $\mathscr{F} \text{close with } \cup$.

are already given and meet the presented required properties.

The remaining probability measure $P$ properties must achieve:

- $P(\Omega)=1$:

$\alpha P_1(\Omega)+(1-\alpha)P_2(\Omega)=\alpha+(1-\alpha)=1$

- For $A_i$ pairwise disjoint $P(\cup_i A_i)=\sum_i P(A_i)$:

$P(\cup_i A_i)=\alpha P_1(\cup_i A_i)+(1-\alpha)P_2(\cup_i A_i)=\alpha \sum_i P_1(A_i)+(1-\alpha)\sum_i P_2( A_i)=\sum_i \alpha P_1(A_i)+(1-\alpha) P_2( A_i)=\sum_i P(A_i)$